# R base graphics circular histogram

Tags: r, graphics

What would be the best way to draw a circular histogram in R?

My data has this form:

```
    Dir      N
 1: 360  56564
 2:   0     NA
 3: 180 149374
 4: 210  82219
 5: 240  23315
 6: 300  11436
 7: 330  30648
 8:  30  32198
 9:  60  15266
10:  90  14596
11: 120  26267
12: 150  81782
13: 270  10100
```

I have tried using `windrose` function from the circular package but it requires input data in another format.

I have looked into the graphics:: functions and stars looked promising, but nothing concrete so far.

Thanks

Comment: Which one of the variables you would like to plot as an histogram? I am guessing N?

Comment: Yes, N. Dir would be like the x axis.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following with `circular`, but since your data size is small, the plot is not very fancy:

```
library(circular)
df <- read.table(text='Dir      N
 1: 360  56564
 2:   0     NA
 3: 180 149374
 4: 210  82219
 5: 240  23315
 6: 300  11436
 7: 330  30648
 8:  30  32198
 9:  60  15266
10:  90  14596
11: 120  26267
12: 150  81782
13: 270  10100', header=TRUE)
rownames(df) <- NULL
names(df) <- c('dir', 'mag')
df$dir <- circular(as.numeric(df$dir), units='degrees')
df$mag <- df$mag / 10000 # scale magnitude
windrose(df, breaks=circular(seq(0, 2 * pi, by = pi/4)), increment=5)
```

[image]

With another library `openair` it looks like the following:

```
library(openair)
df <- read.table(text='Dir      N
     1: 360  56564
     2:   0     NA
     3: 180 149374
     4: 210  82219
     5: 240  23315
     6: 300  11436
     7: 330  30648
     8:  30  32198
     9:  60  15266
    10:  90  14596
    11: 120  26267
    12: 150  81782
    13: 270  10100', header=TRUE)
names(df) <- c('wd', 'ws')
df$ws <- df$ws / 10000 # scale speed
windRose(df, angle=45)
```

[image]

The polar coord plot with `ggplot2` looks different (which just converts `geom_bar` into polar coordinates)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=dir, y=mag)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + coord_polar()
```

[image]

Some implementation I tried in `base R` from scratch (just for the idea, the implementation is not very efficient, you can always improve the efficiency of implementation, for example use `polygon` instead of `segments` to fill the arcs), we can use a similar implementation in `base R` to mimic the one in `ggplot`:

```
add.filled.arc <- function(center.x, center.y, radius, angle.start, angle.end, col='black') {
  theta <- seq(angle.start, angle.end, .0001)
  segments(0, 0, radius*cos(theta), radius*sin(theta), col)
  segments(0, 0, cos(angle.start), sin(angle.start), col='gray')
  segments(0, 0, cos(angle.end), sin(angle.end), col='gray')
}

plot.coord.polar <- function(df) {
  df <- df[complete.cases(df),]
  df <- df[order(df[,1]),]
  df[,1] <- df[,1]*(pi/180) # convert dir to radian
  df[,2] <- df[,2] / max(df[,2]) # normalize magnitude within [0-1]
  plot(-1:1, -1:1, type= 'n', xlab='', ylab='', xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
  sapply(1:(nrow(df)-1), function(i) add.filled.arc(0, 0, df[i,2], df[i,1], df[i+1,1], rainbow(nrow(df))[i]))
  theta <- seq(0, 2*pi, 0.0001)
  lines(cos(theta), sin(theta), col='gray')
}

df <- read.table(text='Dir      N
                 1: 360  56564
                 2:   0     NA
                 3: 180 149374
                 4: 210  82219
                 5: 240  23315
                 6: 300  11436
                 7: 330  30648
                 8:  30  32198
                 9:  60  15266
                 10:  90  14596
                 11: 120  26267
                 12: 150  81782
                 13: 270  10100', header=TRUE)
plot.coord.polar(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer, however I ended using another approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mpg)
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar() + coord_polar()
g
```

[image]

For your data, assuming your data frame above is called df, and you want to graph N you would do:

```
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(df, aes(N)) + geom_bar() + coord_polar()
g
```

Comment: Thank you, I know ggplot2 produces beautiful graphs, but I need to use base graphics. `windrose`, for example, uses base to plot it's graph.

Comment: Is `windrose` from another package, it's not in the base I went `?windrose` and `??windrose` and did not find it

Comment: "I have tried using windrose function from the circular package but it requires input data in another format."

Comment: I see, is this a homework @mclzc? why would you be willing to use circular package and not ggplot2? just wondering, not judging anyway :D

Comment: Not is not homework, I just need to stick to base, all my other graphs are in base, so I'd like to keep the look and feel homogeneous.

Comment: @mclzc I will look for options, but nothing so far, you can change the theme of ggplot2 to make it look more baselike though, let me know if you are interested